# running multi module Java program built through Maven gets "Unexpected token" error

Tags: java, maven

Trying to learn Maven using Peggy Fisher's "Multi Module Build Automation with Maven".

main module app has dependent modules createFile, madlib.

trying to run the java program, I am getting

```
java -cp "C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\lynda\app\1.0\app-1.0.jar";"C:\Users\user\Documents\Learn\Maven\Ex_Files_MMB_Maven\Exercise Files\Ch01\01_06\sample-multi-app\createFile\target\createFile-1.0.jar";"C:\Users\user\Documents\Learn\Maven\Ex_Files_MMB_Maven\Exercise Files\Ch01\01_06\sample-multi-app\madLib\target\madLib-1.0.jar" com.lynda.App
At line:1 char:337
+ ... 01\01_06\sample-multi-app\madLib\target\madLib-1.0.jar" com.lynda.App
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'com.lynda.App' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

parent pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <!-- parent coordinates -->
        <parent>
                <groupId>com.lynda</groupId>
                <artifactId>multi-app</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
        </parent>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
        <!-- project coordinates -->
        <groupId>com.lynda</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <!-- project dependencies -->
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.lynda</groupId>
                        <artifactId>createFile</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.lynda</groupId>
                        <artifactId>madLib</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>

        </dependencies>
</project>
```

App.java

```
package com.lynda;

import com.lynda.createfile.CreateFile;
import com.lynda.madlib.MadLib;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
               
              
           CreateFile.getWords();
           //make sure you update the absolute file location with your project information
           MadLib.createMadLib("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Learn\\Maven\\Ex_Files_MMB_Maven\\Exercise Files\\Ch01\\01_06\\sample-multi-app\\words.txt");
          
        }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether it is due to maven at all. Can't you just place those jar files in classpath and then just run the compiled file ?

Comment: I did place the jars in classpath if you see the command I ran.

Comment: I know. What I mean is instead of dynamically passing them via java command just place those files in the actual classpath and then execute just ur java file.